# scp to an alias

Tags: bash, alias, arguments

To transfer a folder from my local host to a remote host, I normally do:

```
$ scp -r myFolder user@host:destFolder/
```

Trying to make this easier, I aliased the remote host destination:

```
$ alias remoteHost user@host:destFolder/
```

However, scping to the alias doesn't work:

```
$ scp -r myFolder `remoteHost`
bash: user@host:destFolder/: No such file or directory
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

Comment: Have you restarted your system after you made the alias? Sometimes it helps to restart before trying an alias..

Comment: @ryekayo Aliases do not work this way, so restarting wouldn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`alias` allows a string to be substituted for a word since when it is used as the first word of a simple command, not string for string like you want.

You should use variable instead:

```
remoteHost='user@host:destFolder/'
scp -r myFolder "$remoteHost"
```